# Port forwarding to a VMware machine via iptables

Tags: vmware, iptables, portforwarding, vmware-player

Linux server with virtual machine run by VMware Player. Within the server, Firefox can access the IP address of the virtual machine. Yet it is unreacheable from the outside world ("Connection reset" error).

Iptables are configured followingly:

```
[root@linuxserver ~]# iptables -L -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:gw to:172.16.75.1:3010
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:trusted-web to:172.16.75.1:3011

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere            anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Any ideas? Or at least any way/tool (beside `ping` and `traceroute`) for tracing packets so as to localize problematic spot more precisely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When one changes virtual router's configuration (e. g. `/etc/vmware/vmnet8/nat/nat.conf`), one needs to restart the VMware service. That is, kill all running VMware instances and restart via

```
sudo service vmware restart
```